# Question related to toplogical sorting

Tags: graph-theory

Now the question is related to online banking. It states that like in online banking for security banks never ask the whole password but instead they may ask for 3 random numbers in their password.

For example if the password is 52842 and the bank asks for the $1^{st}, 2^{nd}$ and $4^{th}$ number one has to enter 524. Now the bank can ask for any 3 random numbers but they will always be in order.

So if one enters 743. Then 7 comes before in the password. Then comes 4 and then 3.

Now one is given about 50 3 digits numbers and one has to come up with an algorithm that analyses the file and determine the shortest possible password.

Now I just analysed the file and through brute force was able to come with the shortest password in under 5 minutes.

Now they've given a hint alongside the question: "The problem can be set up as a topological sorting problem if you can construct the appropriate DAG." I don't know how to do this method through the method mentioned in the hint and write the specific algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the valid characters are the ten digits, set up a $10\times10$ array $G$. Read the list of $3$-digit numbers; when you read $ijk$, set $G(i,j),G(i,k)$, and $G(j,k)$ to $1$. When you’re done, $G$ is the adjacency matrix of a transitive DAG in which there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ if and only if $i$ must precede $j$ in the password. Now apply any topological sorting algorithm to this graph; the first one described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms) is simple and easy to understand.